# Web Animation API with Scroll-driven animation is only animating (fading in) one item instead of all items in the forEach

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll, web-animations-api

This is a fairly new experimental animation needing a polyfill (https://rawcdn.githack.com/flackr/scroll-timeline/55c54c10ccf3308f36c09cbca4935286fe99f14f/dist/scroll-timeline.js), but according to Bram.us will be coming soon to browsers. I don't want to use GreenSock's ScrollTrigger. I have one item animating but I don't see why the rest won't animate. Each piece of armor is a separate element that I want to come in one at a time with scrolling and then each come back off on reverse scrolling.

See at: https://armor.byuiwebdev.com

Bram.us has a cactus example in his scroll-driven collection on codepen that does a similar thing but I also could not get that code to work either. All items come in at the same time with that example.

Answer (score 0):

The [cactus example you are referring to](https://codepen.io/bramus/pen/RwGqxdv) is using the old `@scroll-timeline` syntax.

Since creating that demo, the Scroll-Linked Animations Specification and its proposed syntax have undergone a major rewrite, so the example is no longer syntactically valid. This notice is also included in the demo itself.

Note that the concept of a Scroll-Linked Animation still stands, it’s only the syntax that has changed since creating the demo.

To learn about the new syntax, please refer to these resources:

- Article: https://developer.chrome.com/articles/scroll-driven-animations/.
- Demos: https://scroll-driven-animations.style/